# Problema na geração de um gráfico dinâmico no vis.js

Tags: javascript, gráfico

Estou com um problema nessa biblioteca gráfica: http://visjs.org/

Os dados estão corretos (e estão corretos no gráfico também), porém visualmente eles não estão sendo representados corretamente. Exemplo:

[image]

O nó vermelho possui ligação com o nó azul. O nó verde possui ligação com o nó preto

Problema: O nó vermelho passa dentro do nó verde até o azul, apesar do nó verde não possuir ligação com o nó azul. Visualmente mostra que o nó verde possui ligação com o azul, apesar de não possuir.

Código de configuração do gráfico:

```
var options = {
layout: {
  hierarchical: {
    direction: "UD",
    sortMethod: "directed"
  }
},
interaction: {dragNodes :false},
physics: {
  enabled: false
},
configure: {
  filter: function (option, path) {
    if (path.indexOf('hierarchical') !== -1) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  },
  showButton:false
}
```

O gráfico está no modo Hierárquico: http://visjs.org/docs/network/layout.html

Já tentei usar o "physics" e algumas outras soluções que foram respondidas aqui no stackoverflow (Inglês e BR), mas nada deu certo